# window.open() does not open when clicked more than once

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, jsp, pdf

In my JSP application, I have a javascript function that opens a new window. The reportURL is a call to an asp application that produces a pdf file. So, if you call that asp page, it will produce pdf data.

The javascript that I have is:

```
function openReport(id)
{
    window.open('<%=reportUrl%>&id='+id,
                '_blank',
                'width=900 height=900 scrollbars=yes status=yes'
               );
}
```

Now my application runs fine, when the report link is clicked, it opens a new window and I can view my pdf. However, when I close the pdf report window and click the link again to generate report, it opens a new window (without the pdf). This new window does not look like a blank window as the background is not white, rather it looks like the pdf plugin for the browser recognizes it is pdf as I can see grey background but I cannot view the document.

Can anyone please let me know where is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a browser specific problem, have you tested different browsers? Is it the same result?

Comment: No, I am working on a legacy JSP code which runs only on IE, so unfortunately I cannot test this on other browsers.. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Sounds to me like you may be generating a report on the fly when the url is opened?  If that's true, what's the backend code for it look like?  Is it possible that it will / can only generate the report one time, and subsequent loads aren't going to generate a full new report?  You can check that the proper URL is opening / being requested by using fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: Test it in other browsers by copy/pasting the url. First check if copy/pasting into IE gives you the same issue in your question, then see if it is the same in other browsers. PDF's can cause some strange issues and I trust IE even less than I do Adobe's PDF plugin.

Comment: I checked that.. copy pasting the URL in IE works no matter how many times and how many windows I open. The problem is only when I try and open it through window.open() command..

@PriorityMark, yes I am trying to generate the report on the fly. The backend code takes some parameters from the JSP application and generates a PDF. If I try this by copy pasting the URL, it works fine, so the problem has to be with the window.open in IE..

Comment: So, just curious. Does window.open work normally on your system when not opening a PDF?

Comment: @Matthew, yup it does.. apparently this is not just happening on my computer, it is the same on other computers running IE as well..

Comment: Which version of IE are you targeting?

Comment: I am testing this in IE-8 and it doesn't work.. could this be with the PDF plugin in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is its a caching issue of some kind. Whether its caching the window itself, or the results of the URL I can't tell without investigating it. Two things I would try, naming the window with a random name that changes every time you click it so instead of '_blank' use `(new Date()).toString()` (or similar I haven't tested it). The second thing to try is to ensure that the URL is unique every time to avoid caching there, so choose a querystring variable thats not used by the reporting system and change that every time its clicked e.g. `+ 'version='+(new Date()).toString()`.

This jquery popup window code works if you click it twice, so be helpful in determining what works and what doesn't http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

In fact you can conduct your own test, change the URL in your popup to a regular website and see how it works, if it works normally you know its the content not the window.

Hopefully that gives a starting point - unfortunately its hard to give a exact answer without being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for your effort and for your suggestions.. In fact I did try changing the URL every time the report was requested, however, it does not display the content. For that matter, once the report window is closed, the browser does not open any PDF report links (from my JSP application).. and if I open some random pdf URL on a separate tab, it loads the file properly, and now I can even generate my earlier report (but only once).. is there something else  that I can try?

Comment: And have you tried giving the new window a random new name each time?